# How can I mimic "load-file"  behavior with use ?  

Tags: namespaces, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

Hi guys : I want to see all the functions in my namespace, from the repl (for quick hacking and testing).

How does use differ from load  ?

I notice that if I "load-file" x, all imports are now in my namespace (even those which are external to the file).

HOWEVER if I "use" x (by referring to x's namespace) , those classes imported in x are **not** available at the repl.

Is there a way that I can get use to mimic the way that load-file includes file imports into my repl  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

special forms like `use` are well... special. you can't write functions that 'use' namespaces into the callers ns. But a simple macro can save you!

I did this in a project back before I had leiningen to load my repl properly

```
(defmacro load-all []
  '(use 
   :reload-all
   'com.cryptovide.modmath
   'com.cryptovide.combine
   'com.cryptovide.split
   'com.cryptovide.encrypt
   'com.cryptovide.misc
   'com.cryptovide.decrypt
   'com.cryptovide.modmathTest
   'com.cryptovide.combineTest
   'com.cryptovide.splitTest
   'com.cryptovide.encryptTest
   'com.cryptovide.miscTest
   'com.cryptovide.decryptTest
   'com.cryptovide.testlib
   'com.cryptovide.gui
   'com.cryptovide.checksum
   'com.cryptovide.log))
```

When you call this, the reader runs the `use`es from the namespace that you call it in (for example it will `use` them into the repl's current *ns*

Comment: Not true. `use` is a plain old function implemented on top of primitives like `require` and (I think) `intern`.

Answer (score 1):

use imports all the public vars into the current namespace. is that not what you want?

Example:

```
user> (use 'clojure.pprint)
nil
user> (pprint [:foo])
[:foo]
nil
```

Comment: You are correct, I clarified the question.  I mean, that I want the imports of my x.clj file to be loaded into my repl.  I have a single "x.clj" file which is importing alot of classes, and I want those class methods to be callable from the repl after a single call to (use 'x).

Answer (score 1):

Well, don't do that :P. If you want to be in a particular namespace, then instead of pretending with some sort of crazy `use` to import everything to the `user` ns, why not just actually go into that namespace? `(require 'myns) (in-ns 'myns)` does that, or a handy shortcut `(doto 'myns require in-ns)`.

Comment: hmm okay.  looks like this removes the standard repl imports. is there a way to retain those ?  For example, the (source) macro won't work anymore....